# I am trying to build a concatenated dictionary from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a vinyl album dictionary that a programme generates ('sample_music_dict') below into a new dictionary (see below, 'new_music_dict') that concatenates the albums by artist into single list where the artist becomes the key. I will then use this new dictionary to produce prints, screen lists and other things.

**Source dictionary**. This is the dictionary I want to convert from

```
sample_music_dict = {
    
    'A-HA': [
        'A-Ha',
        ['HEADLINES & DEADLINES', 'Headlines & Deadlines', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'ABC': [
        'Abc',
        ['THE LEXICON OF LOVE', 'The Lexicon Of Love', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'AC/DC': [
        'Ac/Dc',
        ['BACK IN BLACK', 'Back In Black', 'Jan-17', ''],
        ['HIGHWAY TO HELL', 'Highway to Hell', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'JON ANDERSON': [
        'Jon Anderson',
        ['3 SHIPS', '3 Ships', 'Nov-19', ''],
        ['IN THE CITY OF ANGELS', 'In The City Of Angels', 'Jan-17', ''],
        ['OLIAS OF SUNHILLOW', 'Olias of Sunhillow', 'Jan-17', '']
    ]

}
```

**Target dictionary**. This is the dictionary I want to convert to

```
new_music_dict = {
    'Abba':['Abba Greatest Hits Vol.2'],
    'ABC':['The Lexicon Of Love'],
    'AC/DC':['Back In Black','Highway to Hell'],
    'All About Eve':['All About Eve'],
    'Jon  Anderson':['3 Ships','In The City Of Angels','Olias of 
    Sunhillow']
    }
```

To solve this problem I tried to iterate though the source dictionary by using code for and while statements, but I couldn't work out how to pull data into the list format that I need.

For example if I break down the source dictionary to it's basic form, it has a KEY (artist name UPPER case) the  VALUE is a list containing the artist name in Title Case, followed by multiple lists - one list for each album for the artist. In each sub list at is the album name and three other pieces of information about the album.
Like so:

```
sample_music_dict = {
'KEY': 
['Value' 
['L1_0 - Album Nme', 'L1_1- Info1', 'L1_2- Info2', 'L1_3- Info3',
 ['L2_0 - Album Nme', 'L2_1- Info1', 'L2_2- Info2', 'L2_3- Info3'],
  ['L3_0 - Album Nme', 'L3_1- Info1', 'L3_2- Info2', 'L3_3- Info3'], 
   ['L4_0 - Album Nme', 'L4_1- Info1', 'L4_2- Info2', 'L4_3- Info3']
}
```

what I want to produce is a dictionary that has the KEY as the Artist name and then one list with all the album names for that artist. Like the outline below:

```
new_music_dict = {
  'KEY': ['L1_0 - Album Nme','L2_0 - Album Nme',
  'L3_0 - Album Nme','L4_0 - Album Nme'] 
  }
```

The real data there may be 10 albums for an artist or just two so the no of albums can be variable.

Once I can produce the target dictionary format that I want, I can then use the new dictionary produce tabular data outputs (PrettyTable or TextTable) and also create different features in my programme.

Any help or suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for editing your original question, and for putting so much effort into it! Here's a solution that seems to work:

```
import pprint

sample_music_dict = {
    
    'A-HA': [
        'A-Ha',
        ['HEADLINES & DEADLINES', 'Headlines & Deadlines', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'ABC': [
        'Abc',
        ['THE LEXICON OF LOVE', 'The Lexicon Of Love', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'AC/DC': [
        'Ac/Dc',
        ['BACK IN BLACK', 'Back In Black', 'Jan-17', ''],
        ['HIGHWAY TO HELL', 'Highway to Hell', 'Jan-17', '']
    ],

    'JON ANDERSON': [
        'Jon Anderson',
        ['3 SHIPS', '3 Ships', 'Nov-19', ''],
        ['IN THE CITY OF ANGELS', 'In The City Of Angels', 'Jan-17', ''],
        ['OLIAS OF SUNHILLOW', 'Olias of Sunhillow', 'Jan-17', '']
    ]

}

def get_pairs():
    from operator import itemgetter
    for key, value in sample_music_dict.items():
        yield key, list(map(itemgetter(1), value[1:]))

new_music_dict = dict(get_pairs())

pprint.pprint(new_music_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A-HA': ['Headlines & Deadlines'],
 'ABC': ['The Lexicon Of Love'],
 'AC/DC': ['Back In Black', 'Highway to Hell'],
 'JON ANDERSON': ['3 Ships', 'In The City Of Angels', 'Olias of Sunhillow']}
>>>
```

The `pprint` module is not strictly required, it's just so I can get a pretty-printed output. You were saying that you want the strings in the lists to come from the first "column" (index) of each album list - but shouldn't it be the second index, rather than the first? Since the first index contains the all-caps title... This solution assumes that the album title we want is at the second index of each album list.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question and hopefully explained what I want to solve ore clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @milesabc123 Thanks, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Paul, many thanks for the suggestion, it worked really well. I was wondering if I wanted to extract the album name and the date can the code you provided be amended to handle multiple indexes in a list? thanks

Comment: @milesabc123 Glad it's working. To get both the album name and date, you can simply change `itemgetter(1)` to `itemgetter(1, 2)`. This will yield key-value pairs, where the values are lists of tuples, however. I don't know if that's what you want. What would be the desired output in that case?

Answer (score 0):

so what I thought I could try is to extract multiple pieces of information from my data. for example a recipe programme:

'''
sample_data = {'PERFECT PANCAKES RECIPE':
['Perfect pancakes recipe', ['100g plain flour', '2 eggs', '300ml semi-
skimmed milk', '1 tbsp sunflower oil or vegetable, plus extra for frying',
'pinch salt'],['1. Put 100g plain flour and a pinch of salt into a large
mixing bowl.', '2. Make a well in the centre and crack 2 eggs into the
middle.'], 'bbc']
}

```
def get_pairs_new():
    from operator import itemgetter
    for key, value in sample_data.items():
        yield key, list(map(itemgetter(1), value[1:]))


recipe = dict(get_pairs_new())
print(new_music_dict)


t = Texttable()
for key, value in recipe.items():
artist = key
album = ("\n".join(value))
t.add_rows([['Artist', 'Album'], [artist, album]])
print(t.draw())
```

'''

And then be able to print in a table the name, ingredients and instructions and source of the recipe. If I change itemgetter(1) to itemgetter(1,2) it returns a tuple an then the programme crashes.
Thanks